# How to position an image behind autotable in jspdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to make my autotables to overlay the images in my document but the available options don't seem to work. I found a way to make it done like this:

```
doc.internal.events.subscribe('addPage', function() { doc.addImage(myImage, 'JPG', 5, 265, 20, 30); });
```

But this solution would only apply from the second page ahead. I would like it to work also in the initial page. Is it fine to use this solution? How could I get it to work also in the first page?

Thanks.

Comment: wrap the image in a div, then set the style of the div:
style="z-index:-1"

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I am not using HTML but just Javascript to generate the PDF. Not sure how to use html tags the way I am doing it. I have seen in the documentation that you can render with html2canvas but it would involve to rewrite my reports. Isn't there a workaround using just Javascript so I don't have to redo what I already have?

Comment: If you are using JavaScript then you can still modify the DOM, get the element using getElementById then set its style with el.style.zIndex = -1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept digging and I found out that in jsPDF the elements are rendered on top of the previous one, so I just added the image in the beginning of the code specifying the coordinates in the bottom of the page where I wanted it and it worked. Having that information it is easy to position the elements similar as to z-index does.

I hope this is useful to someone else. Thanks!